# jasmine test case does not return from mongo save

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jasmine, bdd, jasmine-node

I am using https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node to test my nodejs server routes.
My mongoose model has a working pre function as below

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
         if (err) return next(err);

             logger.info('Hashing password!!!');

             bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
                  if (err) return next(err);
                  user.password = hash;
                  next();
             });
      });
});
```

Now I need to write a test case in jasmine that creates a userSchema object and saves it to mongodb to use it further in my test case.

```
var User = require("../../../../models/User");

            it("{postLogin - invalid}", function(done) {
                var user = new User({email: "test@test.com", password: "a"});

                user.save(function(err) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return next(err);
                }
                console.log('user saved to db: ' +user.email);  
                request.post(invalidLoginParams, function(error, response, body) {
                    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(400);
                    done();
                });              
            });
    },15000);
```

I run the above test case using jasmine-node and i get the log **'Hashing password!!!'** which means it is calling this function.
But after this it never returns to my test case. It should print the log **'user saved to db: '**
But it is never returning back from .pre('save') function.
Any idea where and what am i missing. Could not find any answer on google. Hope to get it here!
Thanks

Comment: It look like you have to call `done` in jasmine when `user.save` have error.

Comment: @greenlikeorange Can you elaborate? coz `done()` is called if there is no error. And there is no error in `save`. It just does not come back from save to my testcase.

Comment: `done` is need to call anytime when your job is done, if you have error you have to call `return done(error)` instance of `return next(err)`. Then you can know, there is error or not at logs

Comment: ok i tried this. Added `done(err)` instead of `return(err)`.  It does not throw an error. it is just stuck and does not return from `save` . Nobody has a solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please make sure to call the callback "done()" properly.